# Where does the phrase "doctored" originate?

Tags: etymology

This is a phrase I’m particularly confused about, because it’s used often when something is manipulated or changed.

For example, sometimes images surface online that are clearly Photoshopped, but people refer to them as “doctored” images. Why use the word “doctored” here?

Comment: [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doctor?q=doctor). Sense 2 of the verb has been extended into becoming sense 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest Google Books match for an instance of *doctored* in a transitional (or perhaps post-transitional) sense between "amended" and "adulterated" appears in William Marshall, [*The Rural Economy of Glocestershire; Including Its Dairy: Together with the Dairy Management of North Wiltshire, and the Management of Orchards and Fruit Liquor, in Herefordshire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kXtXj9GlF90C&pg=PA304&dq=%22it+must+be+doctored+or+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX5Mm35tnaAhXJqlQKHTvRCNkQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22it%20must%20be%20doctored%20or%20if%22&f=false), volume 2 (1789):

> Men in general, however, whose palates are set to rough cider, consider the common sweet sort as an effeminate beverage; and rough cider, properly manufactured, is probably the most generous liquor; being deemed more wholesome, to habits in general, than sweet cider:—even when genuine. That which is drank, in the kingdom at large, is too frequently adulterated. The "ciderman" *cannot afford* to lose a hogshead: if it will not *do*, it must be "***doctored***": or if sound, it may not be sweet enough for the palate of his customers; nor high enough coloured to please the eye; but the requisite colour and sweetness, he finds, are easily communicated.

This is evidently the sense of "doctored" that appears as OED definition 3 in tchrist's  answer:

> **3.** *fig.* To treat so as to alter the appearance, flavour, or character of; to disguise, falsify, tamper with, adulterate, sophisticate, ‘cook’.

And yet it is not so very distant from the OED's definition 2b (again as quoted in tchrist's answer):

> **2b.** *transf.* To repair, patch up, set to rights.

The line between "repair, patch up, set to rights" and "disguise, falsify, tamper with, adulterate" is not clearly demarcated—certainly not if you are a ciderman stuck with a hogshead of cider that no one will buy in its present state. Rather, it's a continuum that begins innocently enough with making improvements that are to everyone's advantage, and only gradually gives way to disguising an inferior product without acknowledging its original shortcomings or—in the worst case—without actually improving it at all. In this respect, it mimics the difference between sound medicine at one end of the continuum and quackery at the other.

Answer (score 5):

The adjective *doctored* derives from the figurative use of the verb *doctor*, meaning per the OED:

> To treat so as to alter the appearance, flavour, or character of; to disguise, falsify, tamper with, adulterate, sophisticate, ‘cook’.

The first citation is from the 18<sup>th</sup> century.

In case it helps you see how these things developed, here from the OED, minus the citations, are all the senses given for ***doctor*** verb, including this one:

> **1**. *trans.* To confer the degree or title of Doctor upon; to make a Doctor.
>
> **2a**. To treat, as a doctor or physician; to administer medicine or medical treatment to.
>
> **2b**. *transf.* To repair, patch up, set to rights.
>
> **2c**. To castrate (an animal).
>
> **3**. *fig.* To treat so as to alter the appearance, flavour, or character of; to disguise, falsify, tamper with, adulterate, sophisticate, ‘cook’.
>
> **4**. *intr.* **a.** To practise as a physician. (Usually in *vbl. sb.* or *pr. pple.*)
>
> **4b**. To take medicine, undergo medical treatment.
>
> Hence **ˈdoctored** *ppl. a.*, **ˈdoctoring** *vbl. sb.*; also **ˈdoctorer**, one who doctors.

It should be pretty clear how the straightforward sense 2a turned into the transferred sense 2b, and thence to sense 3 by figurative extension.

This shows  why it is important that senses be listed in the historical order that they came into the language, not merely by order of each sense’s currency or popularity.

Comment: But how does the word "doctor" tie in with "doctored"

Comment: @Retrosaur I don’t understand the question that you have done me the honor to pose in your comment.  Surely if I doctor something, then that thing has *ipso facto* been doctored, just as if I cook something it becomes cooked and if I falsify something it becomes falsified. There is nothing more to it than this.

Comment: Why is the verb form have such a different meaning from the noun form? From google: doctor: A qualified practitioner of medicine; a physician

Comment: The verb form does not “have a different meaning from the noun form”. Your mistake is that Google is not a real dictionary. The OED has 7 senses for the verb *doctor* to accompany the 22 senses it has for the noun *doctor*. It makes perfect sense seen in that light.

Comment: Why? There's no explanation possible for this one instance. It just happens. Word change meanings. Why does 'run' in "you have a run in your stocking" mean something other than running. It happens _all_ the time. Most entries in a (good) dictionary will have multiple entries for a word.

Comment: @Mitch Actually, here there is a clear explanation: it is a perfectly sensible figurative sense of something that’s been patched up.

Comment: @tchrist oh. Sure. I thought the OP was concerned -that- words change meanings, as opposed to how 'a doctor' is related to 'to doctor'.

Comment: I was more or less concerned with how "doctor" related to "doctored'.

Comment: @Retrosaur  Almost any English word, whatever word class it starts in, may be used in a pinch as any other part of speech. Very often such uses become widely accepted in the language as new senses of. Thus, the activity of **a doctor** became the verb **to doctor** a wound or a disease or a patient. Later that sense was extended to figurative repairs of a machine or an ill-prepared dish; then **that* sense was extended still farther to "repairs" of things that don't need repairing: for instance, 'doctoring' milk with water, or 'doctoring' images which don't look quite right.

Comment: @StoneyB Your comment was more or less what I was aiming for in my question; I just worded it badly

Comment: @Retrosaur  Of course; and if you read tchrist's answer carefully you will see he has said exactly the same thing as I have; only what's obvious to him is not obvious to you, and vice versa.

Comment: To note: The *OED* updated the entry for *doctor* in 2022, and the entries are expanded and reordered.