# The etymology of doctoring text

Tags: etymology, british-english

I was gutted today that I failed The Times crossword on one clue - "writings not considered genuine", which I've now come to know is "apocrypha". While trying to give a clue to others, I went off course (I first thought) and talked about fantasy MMORPG games where we used to fight Apothecaries.

I've since seen the formal definition of "apothecary" and it's pretty innocent:

> † originally. One who kept a store or shop of non-perishable
> commodities, spices, drugs, comfits, preserves, etc. This passed at an
> early period into the next: in 1617 the Apothecaries' Company of
> London was separated from the Grocers'.

However, what strikes me now is that we can say that text has been "doctored" if it has been faked or altered in some way. Thinking about that properly, it's a very strange term to use, so I have a couple of etymological questions:

1. Are the words "apocrypha" and "apothecary" related at all?
2. Even though "(to) doctor" text is so far removed from those words, did we inherit the concept and somehow pull it into modern English from that origin, even when it doesn't make sense logically? We expect doctors to be truthful and honest and yet I'm only now questioning the sense of the verb

Comment: These are two _completely unrelated_ questions. Please post them separately.

Comment: And question 1 can be answered by looking at any dictionary which gives etymologies.

Comment: I'm not sure they're unrelated. "apocrypha" and "apothecary" is in the past, and now we have "doctors" and "to doctor". If I split it up, I don't think any of it would make sense. I'm asking whether the association was carried forward

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413985/how-did-to-doctor-come-to-mean-to-falsify

Comment: Apocryphal text is not at heart doctored text, though it may. So what we have is forcing the word *doctored* in for voila! a connection. This coincidence has the makings of a smart play on words or poetry. Clever.

Comment: Do not expect the meanings of words to match their etymologies.  The prefixes "apo" are the same, from Greek ἀπό (from, away).  But the stems are different: *apocrypha* from κρυφος (hidden) and *apothecary* from θήκη (somewhere you put things).  Meanwhile *doctor* has a Latin origin and was a title essentially meaning teacher.

Comment: @Henry So the original meaning is what we see in "Doctor of Philosophy". The meaning doctor == physician is a later specialization?

Comment: The relationship between _apocrypha_ and _apothecary_ is the same as the relationship between _conference_ and _consommé_: they are derived from words in another language which have the same prefix. Any closer connection is just in your mind.